Ubuntu 22.04 on Nvidia Jetson temporary failure in name resolution
I'm installing JetPack 6.1 (Ubuntu 22.04 ARM64) on Jetson Orin AGX Developer Kit. The Linux image was flashed successfully and it boots fine. I configured the Ethernet network manually to set a fixed IP address to 192.168.0.42, DNS address to 205.171.3.25, the same as other Ubuntu PCs on my local network, which can access Internet without problems. Jetson is accessible on my LAN, but it can’t access Internet. I tried several procedures suggested in various places with no success. As far as I can tell, the Jetson is configured the same way as other Ubuntu PCs on the network. Here is a log from the Jetson:
nick@ubuntu:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         198.162.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 eno1
0.0.0.0         192.168.55.100  0.0.0.0         UG    32766  0        0 l4tbr0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 l4tbr0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
192.168.55.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 l4tbr0
198.162.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    20100  0        0 eno1
nick@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.42  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 48:b0:2d:91:1b:f0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 714  bytes 37918 (37.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1420  bytes 64483 (64.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

l4tbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.55.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.55.255
        inet6 fe80::3cc7:e7ff:fe79:f387  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3e:c7:e7:79:f3:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1132  bytes 181217 (181.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 334  bytes 78939 (78.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4484  bytes 352621 (352.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4484  bytes 352621 (352.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::84d8:9eff:fe19:f2cd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 86:d8:9e:19:f2:cd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 854  bytes 127712 (127.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 650  bytes 169852 (169.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::84d8:9eff:fe19:f2cf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 86:d8:9e:19:f2:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 290  bytes 55015 (55.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 627  bytes 113012 (113.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlP1p1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 90:e8:68:bc:6a:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nick@ubuntu:~$ resolvectl dns
Global:
Link 2 (can0):
Link 3 (can1):
Link 4 (wlP1p1s0):
Link 5 (eno1): 205.171.3.25
Link 6 (l4tbr0):
Link 7 (usb0):
Link 8 (usb1):
nick@ubuntu:~$ ping  yahoo
ping: yahoo: Temporary failure in name resolution

The only difference I see is in /etc/resolv.conf symlink. The Jetson has only one non-comment line:
nameserver 127.0.0.53

the PCs have three:
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

Also, these nameservers are different from my manual setting and the one shown by resolvectl dns output on all systems.

Reboot doesn't help, but this sequence does:
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient

What is the problem?

Entered Home into Search domains in Advanced Network Configuration and the problem disappeared. /etc/resolv.conf now contains this:
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search Home

